# toggling fullscreen mode with javascript with firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, fullscreen

The firefox add-on I am working on is best viewed in fullscreen mode. (I am not creating a new window, but I insert a transparent div on the body of the current page and display some pictures.) Is there a way to toggle the fullscreen mode or f11 key with javascript?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I overlooked that you're talking about an add-on, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.fullScreen, you should be able to just do `window.fullScreen = true;` (provided that your script is running in the browser window, not some other window, in which case you may have to jump through a couple hoops to get a reference to the main browser window)

> This property indicates whether the
>   window is displayed in full screen
>   mode or not. It is only reliable in
>   Gecko 1.9 (Firefox 3) and later, see
>   the Notes below. With chrome
>   privileges, the property is
>   read-write.

Comment: yes that works... I did not realize that window.fullScreen was writable. Thanks.

Comment: There's issues on osx though, my chrome window is not going perfectly full :( Anyone find  fix for that? Matrix or @artsince ?